# Looking for a midrash concerning aveirot that increase suspicions of oneself in others

Tags: midrash, reward-punishment

Shalom.

I asked this question a few days ago, and quickly deleted it when I realised it was Yom Tov (I am a Noachide). I tried reinstating the question just now, but noticed that it did not go to the front of the queue. So re-doing the question in order to get more views. Apologies.

The question:

I remember reading somewhere that there are certain aveirot that increase suspicions of oneself in others. I suspect that lying may have been the aveirah, or one of the aveirot, but I am not certain.

Does anyone know the midrash I am referring to?

Many thanks for your time.

Comment: Do you mean increases suspiciousness about oneself in others? Distrust? If not, do you remember if the source referenced specific suspicions or types of suspicions?

Comment: Hi @Rabbi Kaii - yes, I mean aveirot that increase suspiciousness about oneself in others. Aveirot that make others distrust one more (even if the aveirot are not known by them). As for your second question, I’m sorry, I don’t remember anything about the suspicions themselves :(

Comment: P.S. I’ve done all the Google searches I can think of. Was certain it was a midrash, but now I’m wondering…

Comment: There are things like Sanhedrin 89b about the liar’s punishment is that even when he speaks the truth, no one believes him or things to do with promiscuity and adultery (Shulchan Aruch, EH 4:15) but that's not quite what you are looking for. It's an interesting question!